# create new column based on the value in various other column values - Using R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
DATA <- data.frame(
  LONDON= c(2,0,1,3,0,1), 
  STOKE = c(45, 40, 6, 22, 16, 10), 
  DERBY = c(5, 9, 8, 9, 2, 3), 
  NEWCASTLE = c(7, 6, 4, 10, 12, 8),
  MANCHESTER = c(2, 12, 1, 7, 8, 3),
  WATFORD = c(9, 2, 4, 6, 13, 6),
  KENT = c(1, 3, 23, 7, 12, 2),
  SURREY = c(2, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4),
  ESSEX = c(4, 12, 7, 9, 5, 1),
  HULL = c(1,3, 2, 4, 3, 1))
```

I wanted to create a "NEW_COL" column, which says "YES" or "NO" based on four different value columns. I want the new column to have a "YES" (otherwise have a ‘NO’) when DERBY or NEWCASTLE or SURREY is > 7 or when KENT or HULL = 2
I also want the "NEW_COL" column to be the second column in my dataset.

I thought something like this (below) would have done it, but it didn't. Any help on what I’m doing wrong here/how to navigate through.

```
DATA2 <- DATA %>% mutate(NEW_COL = ifelse(rowSums(select(., DERBY:NEWCASTLE) > 7 | select(., SURREY >7)  | select(., KENT == 2) | select(., HULL == 2), na.rm = TRUE), 'Yes', 'No'), .before = 2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `if_any` and `.before` to change the position

```
library(dplyr)
DATA <- DATA %>% 
    mutate(NEW_COL = c("NO", "YES")[1 + 
        (if_any(c(DERBY, NEWCASTLE, SURREY), `>`, 7)|
       if_any(c(KENT, HULL), `==`, 2))], .before = 2)
```

-output

```
DATA
   LONDON NEW_COL STOKE DERBY NEWCASTLE MANCHESTER WATFORD KENT SURREY ESSEX HULL
1      2      NO    45     5         7          2       9    1      2     4    1
2      0     YES    40     9         6         12       2    3      8    12    3
3      1     YES     6     8         4          1       4   23      4     7    2
4      3     YES    22     9        10          7       6    7      5     9    4
5      0     YES    16     2        12          8      13   12      1     5    3
6      1     YES    10     3         8          3       6    2      4     1    1
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use an `ifelse` statement with your conditions

```
DATA %>% 
    mutate(NEW_COL = 
               ifelse(DERBY > 7 | NEWCASTLE > 7 | SURREY > 7 |
                             KENT == 2 | HULL == 2, "YES","NO"), .before=2)
```

Output:

```
  LONDON NEW_COL STOKE DERBY NEWCASTLE MANCHESTER WATFORD KENT SURREY ESSEX HULL
1      2      NO    45     5         7          2       9    1      2     4    1
2      0     YES    40     9         6         12       2    3      8    12    3
3      1     YES     6     8         4          1       4   23      4     7    2
4      3     YES    22     9        10          7       6    7      5     9    4
5      0     YES    16     2        12          8      13   12      1     5    3
6      1     YES    10     3         8          3       6    2      4     1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of the `case_when` function as it's very readable and easily modifiable imo.

```
require(tidyverse)

greater_threshold <- 7
equality_value <- 2

df_new <- DATA %>%
  mutate(NEW_COL = case_when(DERBY > greater_threshold ~ "YES",
                             NEWCASTLE  > greater_threshold ~ "YES",
                             SURREY  > greater_threshold ~ "YES",
                             KENT == equality_value ~ "YES",
                             HULL == equality_value ~ "YES",
                             T ~ "NO"),
         .before = 2)
```

Comment: Does this mean one can actually set 2 different thresholds? eg greater_threshold <- 7 and greater_threshold1 <- 5

Comment: @lofus77 yes, you can specify any number of logical constraints. One thing to keep in mind is that the row will be evaluated from the first condition to the last in the order that you set. If a row evaluates to true none of the following conditions will be checked, it will be assigned the value following the tilde. In my example, if Derby is found to be greater than the 7 threshold, none of the other evaluations are performed, the row is assigned the 'YES' variable in the NEW_COL field.

Answer (score 1):

Your `rowSums` attempt was close. You can do -

```
library(dplyr)

DATA %>% 
  mutate(NEW_COL = ifelse(rowSums(select(., DERBY, NEWCASTLE, SURREY) > 7) > 0 | 
                          rowSums(select(., KENT, HULL) == 2) > 0, 'Yes', 'No'), .before = 2)

#  LONDON NEW_COL STOKE DERBY NEWCASTLE MANCHESTER WATFORD KENT SURREY ESSEX HULL
#1      2      No    45     5         7          2       9    1      2     4    1
#2      0     Yes    40     9         6         12       2    3      8    12    3
#3      1     Yes     6     8         4          1       4   23      4     7    2
#4      3     Yes    22     9        10          7       6    7      5     9    4
#5      0     Yes    16     2        12          8      13   12      1     5    3
#6      1     Yes    10     3         8          3       6    2      4     1    1
```